# How to return Excel row and column header values based on a known cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some table data in Excel, and I've used the MAX formula to return the highest value.  Now I need to write a couple formulas that return the values of the intersecting row and column headings based on that highest value.

Here's what the table inside my [sample worksheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ecgqdb2cx7uhs77/FindR%26CVals.xlsx?dl=0) looks like.

```
MaxValue = 106,547            RowValue = ?????
                              ColValue = ?????

          ItemA     ItemB     ItemC     ItemD     ItemE     ItemF

  SiteA   784       3,357     -         77        8         54,789
  SiteB   589       259       89        106,547   56        2,587
  SiteC   635       678       -         9,963     -         26,993
  SiteD   1,257     9         41        589       -         6,520
  SiteE   87        3,688     476       46,719    7,899     369
```

The highest value contained in the table is 106,547.  So I want the formulas to return **ItemD** for the RowValue result and **SiteB** for the ColValue result.

Normally I would come at this in VBA, but this particular approach needs to happen in Excel.  I'm thinking INDEX MATCH is the right approach, because I can obtain the correct values using the following formulas in the worksheet (they don't quite translate to the table I posted above, but I can't post images yet, sorry).

```
RowValue = INDEX($B$4:$G$4,MATCH(C1,$B$6:$G$6,0))

ColValue = INDEX($A$5:$A$9,MATCH(C1,$E$5:$E$9,0))
```

What I need is to be able to find those values without hardcoding the row information.

Comment: Your index match formula is not working? Thats the easiest way to get it. What problem do you face?

Comment: I need a way to adjust the formulas so that they use the position of the MaxValue cell to return the headings associated with it.  In this instance, the highest value is 106,547 — so the formula for the row value should return **ItemD** and the column value **SiteB**.

Comment: are there only 6 columns to search for the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is in the range A1:G6 where A2:A6 contains the Site headers, B1:G1 contains the Item headers and numbers in the range B2:G6, then try this

To get Site header:

In J2

```
=INDEX(A2:A6,SUMPRODUCT((B2:G6=MAX(B2:G6))*(ROW(B2:B6)-ROW(B2)+1)))
```

To get Item header:

In K2

```
=INDEX(B1:G1,SUMPRODUCT((B2:G6=MAX(B2:G6))*(COLUMN(B1:G1)-COLUMN(B1)+1)))
```

**Based on your file:**

In F1

```
=INDEX(A5:A9,SUMPRODUCT((B5:G9=C1)*(ROW(B5:B9)-ROW(B5)+1)))
```

In F2

```
=INDEX(B4:G4,SUMPRODUCT((B5:G9=C1)*(COLUMN(B4:G4)-COLUMN(B4)+1)))
```

[image]